# Postgres easy login with pgpass and alias not working

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am trying to use a one word alias to access a postgres database, the problem I am having is it needs a carriage return to work. Can anyone help me to get it to log in without the carriage return?

This is my alias which is in an environment file I am dotting:

```
alias pgres='psql --host cloudpoc.test.com.au -p 8367 -U kevin -W kev_db'
```

This is my .pgpass file which is in the users home directory:

```
cloudpoc.test.com.au:8367:kev_db:kevin:kevpass123
```

If I type "pgres" then I get a prompt for a password. I have to hit enter again to log in.

Shouldn't it just log me straight in?

Comment: See also the [postgresql service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) which enables "connection parameters to be associated with a single service name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the database connection parameters in a [postgresql service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html) called `~/.pg_service.conf` in you home. Based on your connection string:

```
cloudpoc.test.com.au:8367:kev_db:kevin:kevpass123
```

You would enter the following in `~/.pg_service.conf`:

```
# Kevin's database service
[kev]
host=cloudpoc.test.com.au
port=8367
user=kevin
dbname=kev_db
password=kevpass123
```

And you would then connect to the database with:

```
psql service=kev
```

Answer (score 3):

Prompting for a password is what `-W` is for.  If you don't want that behavior, then don't use `-W`.

Comment: I think you could have added a supplemental explanation: it's quite obvious that `kev_db` is the name of a database and that perhaps what @Scouse_Bob wanted was to say `-d` instead of `-W`. You still got my upvote, but for future reference, scoulding helps less than actually... helping.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is replace the `-W` with `-d`, as in:

```bash
alias pgres='psql --host cloudpoc.test.com.au -p 8367 -U kevin -d kev_db'
```

I have the exact similar case with a horribly long cloud DB name and this solution works like a charm.

In any case, please allow me to highlight Paul Rougieux's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70385761/2571805) which makes for a much more usable alternative to mine / yours. True, with `alias` all this becomes secondary, but still it is worth exploring.